# Target specific Documents folder with SOQL query, by Name if possible

Tags: apex, soql

I have a simple SOQL query which is looking for a file in the Documents object:

```
List<Document> documents = [SELECT Id FROM Document WHERE Name like 'ourLogo%' LIMIT 1];
```

Is there any way for me to target a specific folder?

Preferably by name

Comment: You may want to use **FolderId** field in Document object

Comment: @Ratan I'd much prfer to use the Name if that's at all possible.

Comment: check my Answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<Document> documents = [SELECT Id, FolderId, Folder.Name FROM Document WHERE Folder.Name like 'ourLogo%' LIMIT 1];
```

Comment: Perfect! Much appreciated!